# D3.js stacked bar chart growing to negative direction

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked-chart, stackedbarseries

I am new to D3 and javascripts. I am trying to build an animated vertical stacked bar chart. I found an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dBpv3/2/) for a horizontal stacked bar chart. After tweaking it, I got a vertical stacked bar chart, however, growing downwards. Here is [my edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maggiehu/a9wwje7p/).

Update: after making several tweaks, including the ones suggested by below, this finally works:[final working upward growing stacked bar chart](http://jsfiddle.net/maggiehu/e0r2pzc0/5/)
I feel the place(s) that I need to change should be within this code chunk

```
rects = groups.selectAll('.stackedBar')
        .data(function(d,i) {console.log("data", d,i); return d; })
        .enter()
        .append('rect').attr('class','stackedBar')
        .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.y0); })
        .attr('x', function(d, i) {return xScale(d.x); })
        .attr('height',0)
        .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand());

        console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".stacked"));
        var abc=document.querySelectorAll(".stackedBar");

     rects
        .transition()
        .delay(function(d,i,j){console.log("pre",j); return j*500;})
        .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.y); } )
        .duration(1000);
```

But I searched around and tried to revert the yScale range, the initial position of y, and none of them worked. I also noticed that no matter what, my yAxis is always below my X axis going doward.

Comment: Your bar is growing from the top while your data starts by 0 and your axis is on the top. Do you want to  grow the bar from the bottom up (starting by 1200+) or change the whole orientation and have your x-axis at the bottom as well?

Comment: I want to have the x axis at the bottom and then the bars grow upward, one after another, just like the original example shows, but in vertical direction.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must change the orientation of your y-scale:

```
yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,yMax]).range([height,0])
```

And the x-axis must be transformed as well so it start at "height". In svg the top has height=0 so the bottom of your svg equals "height":

```
svg.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'axis')
   .call(xAxis)
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
```

Last but not least, you have to change the building orientation of your stacked bar chart like:

```
rects
   .transition()
   .delay(function(d,i,j){console.log("pre",j); return j*500;})
   .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y + d.y0); })
   .attr("height", function (d) { return yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y + d.y0); } )
   .duration(1000);
```

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3TW3/a9wwje7p/3/).

Comment: yes! your answer is exactly the same to the changes I just spent 4 hours to figure out by myself... I wish I could have seen this earlier. Thanks and I guess I still learned a bunch during the four hours of reading other people's examples and trying numerous approaches.

Comment: Well done! I think it is a good way to learn when you try to formulate a good question and discuss it with some other people.

Answer (score 1):

SVG's start from top left hand corner, so the 'height' specified means the height down the page, so some things work in reverse of what you expect.

Firstly start with your y-scale: the range needs to be mapped in the reverse order (height,0) rather than (0,height).

```
yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,yMax]).range([height,0]),1
```

Likewise, the x-axis needs to be transformed to start at the 'height' .

```
        svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        .call(xAxis)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");'
```

Comment: I made the changes per your suggestion. The x axis now is at the bottom and the y axis is now above x axis, which is a big progress. However, the actual ticks is still in reverse order: 1200 is at the bottom and 0 is at the top.

Comment: Just made some more change, including changing the final value of 'y' and 'height'. Now this works exactly like I want. working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/maggiehu/e0r2pzc0/5/